# Estimating gamma distribution parameters using sample mean and std

Tags: distributions, estimation, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to estimate the parameters of a **gamma distribution** that fits best to my data sample. I only want to use the *mean*, *std* (and hence *variance*) from the data sample, not the actual values - since these won't always be available in my application.

According to [this](https://www.rocscience.com/help/swedge/webhelp/swedge/Gamma_Distribution.htm) document, the following formulas can be applied to estimate the shape and scale:
[image: formulas]

I tried this for my data, however the results are very different compared to fitting a gamma distribution on the actual data using a python programming library.

I attach my data/code to show the issue at hand:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma

data = [91.81, 10.02, 27.61, 50.48, 3.34, 26.35, 21.0, 79.27, 31.04, 8.85, 109.2, 15.52, 11.03, 41.09, 10.75, 96.43, 109.52, 33.28, 7.66, 65.44, 52.43, 19.25, 10.97, 586.52, 56.91, 157.18, 434.74, 16.07, 334.43, 6.63, 108.41, 4.45, 42.03, 39.75, 300.17, 4.37, 343.19, 32.04, 42.57, 29.53, 276.75, 15.43, 117.67, 75.47, 292.43, 457.91, 5.49, 17.69, 10.31, 58.91, 76.94, 37.39, 64.46, 187.25, 30.0, 9.94, 83.05, 51.11, 17.68, 81.98, 4.41, 33.24, 20.36, 8.8, 846.0, 154.24, 311.09, 120.72, 65.13, 25.52, 50.9, 14.27, 17.74, 529.82, 35.13, 124.68, 13.21, 88.24, 12.12, 254.32, 22.09, 61.7, 88.08, 18.75, 14.34, 931.67, 19.98, 50.86, 7.71, 5.57, 8.81, 14.49, 26.74, 13.21, 8.92, 26.65, 10.09, 7.74, 21.23, 66.35, 31.81, 36.61, 92.29, 26.18, 20.55, 17.18, 35.44, 6.63, 69.0, 8.81, 19.87, 5.46, 29.81, 122.01, 57.83, 33.04, 9.91, 196.0, 34.26, 34.31, 36.55, 7.74, 6.68, 6.83, 18.83, 6.6, 50.78, 95.65, 53.91, 81.62, 57.96, 26.72, 76.25, 5.48, 4.43, 133.04, 33.37, 45.26, 30.51, 9.98, 11.08, 28.95, 71.25, 70.65, 3.34, 12.28, 111.67, 139.86, 23.34, 30.0, 26.38, 33.51, 1112.64, 25.87, 148.59, 552.79, 11.11, 47.8, 7.8, 9.98, 7.69, 85.46, 3.59, 122.71, 32.09, 82.51, 12.14, 12.57, 8.8, 49.61, 95.41, 26.99, 13.29, 4.57, 7.78, 4.4, 6.66, 12.17, 12.18, 1533.01, 22.95, 15.93, 14.82, 2.2, 12.04, 9.94, 17.64, 6.66, 18.64, 83.66, 142.99, 30.76, 67.57, 9.88, 46.44, 19.5, 22.2, 43.1, 653.67, 9.86, 7.69, 7.74, 27.19, 38.64, 12.32, 182.34, 43.13, 3.28, 14.32, 69.78, 32.2, 17.66, 18.67, 4.4, 9.05, 56.94, 33.32, 13.2, 15.07, 12.73, 3.32, 35.44, 14.35, 66.68, 51.28, 6.86, 75.49, 5.54, 21.0, 24.2, 38.1, 13.31, 7.78, 5.76, 51.86, 11.09, 20.71, 36.74, 21.97, 10.36, 32.04, 96.94, 13.93, 51.84, 6.88, 27.58, 100.56, 20.97, 828.16, 6.63, 32.15, 19.92, 253.23, 25.35, 23.35, 17.6, 43.18, 19.36, 13.7, 3.31, 22.99, 26.58, 4.43, 2.22, 55.46, 22.34, 13.24, 86.18, 181.29, 52.15, 5.52, 21.12, 34.24, 49.78, 14.37, 39.73, 78.22, 26.6, 20.19, 26.57, 105.8, 11.08, 46.47, 52.82, 13.46, 8.0, 7.74, 49.73, 4.4, 5.44, 51.7, 28.64, 8.95, 9.15, 4.46, 21.03, 29.92, 19.89, 4.38, 19.94, 7.77, 23.43, 57.07, 86.5, 12.82, 103.85, 39.63, 8.83, 42.32, 17.02, 14.29, 16.75, 24.4, 27.97, 8.83, 8.91, 24.23, 6.58, 30.97, 150.58, 122.73, 17.69, 37.11, 11.05, 298.23, 25.58, 9.91, 38.85, 17.24, 82.17, 42.11, 3.29, 38.63, 27.55, 18.22, 127.16, 57.66, 34.45, 41.26, 45.91, 9.88, 34.48, 484.33, 58.42, 30.09, 6.69, 254.49, 1313.58, 39.89, 3.31, 7.83, 10.98, 13.21, 67.78, 7.77, 117.72, 20.03, 83.23, 31.28, 38.97, 6.63, 6.63, 36.6, 22.12, 154.57, 112.65, 19.88, 674.18, 83.31, 5.54, 8.81, 11.06, 178.33, 30.47, 1180.39, 79.33, 37.74, 86.3, 16.61, 53.94, 52.78, 20.83, 11.15, 26.68, 86.04, 180.26, 99.62, 11.17, 28.74, 56.85, 15.51, 95.37, 44.09, 6.68, 12.14, 6.72, 19.81, 10.05, 34.26, 69.84, 14.35, 17.72, 8.81, 20.86, 37.69, 24.62, 72.11, 8.83, 7.69, 60.79, 20.02, 9.41, 13.24, 29.8, 43.09, 25.34, 174.34, 161.6, 119.34, 30.08, 54.15, 7.74, 249.29, 9.98, 21.87, 38.92, 98.45, 95.07, 7.74, 4.45, 81.98, 12.18, 28.66, 5.58, 59.94, 22.15, 9.98, 18.86, 6.69, 134.97, 13.29, 4.43, 8.88, 5.74, 25.16, 122.39, 3.53, 6.68, 3.4, 17.58, 62.51, 584.3, 46.63, 21.19, 22.14, 5.74, 8.19, 7.74, 7.64, 4.41, 3.32, 130.76, 3.29, 31.04, 3.26, 18.83, 168.31, 7.68, 120.19, 43.95, 747.12, 18.75, 306.24, 29.72, 5.57, 6.65, 53.2, 7.96, 25.34, 25.57, 8.85, 93.59, 92.96, 23.4, 60.0, 6.63, 12.15, 49.98, 39.75, 7.77, 5.73, 18.74, 11.58, 281.32, 13.99, 4.59, 13.35, 25.05, 9.98, 5.58, 91.43, 288.94, 15.43, 7.8, 9.92, 18.69, 6.63, 78.38, 18.86, 63.03, 26.38, 166.41, 27.78, 54.21, 173.32, 11.12, 17.85, 14.43, 31.31, 3.37, 16.63, 5.51, 77.74, 8.89, 17.71, 3.24, 9.28, 22.12, 2.2, 19.41, 12.23, 22.31, 9.36, 18.85, 51.5, 8.3, 23.0, 29.7, 29.81, 4.65, 75.77, 55.52, 144.45, 6.68, 13.26, 72.78, 56.71, 46.35, 6.63, 8.88, 6.61, 41.7, 15.09, 5.51, 18.78, 74.09, 487.0, 27.52, 18.99, 44.18, 41.76, 6.65, 23.62, 175.68, 446.38, 87.13, 165.69, 16.57, 7.88, 16.57, 80.17, 135.75, 3.29, 134.16, 25.58, 45.13, 114.23, 471.15, 97.75, 12.2, 32.01, 62.21, 22.36, 193.55, 210.65, 42.39, 27.57, 106.15, 44.76, 16.6, 134.76, 18.81, 14.76, 7.97, 160.59, 39.21, 60.36, 62.45, 72.18, 91.15, 23.71, 105.04, 70.87, 25.57, 122.09, 60.09, 38.8, 133.87, 4.41, 13.28, 45.63, 45.41, 67.81, 26.68, 97.33, 723.5, 5.51, 164.05, 165.32, 4.45, 57.67, 85.82, 11.56, 12.26, 17.97, 31.04, 76.72, 15.01, 35.88, 32.37, 23.63, 85.57, 9.34, 4.45, 90.25, 73.71, 45.99, 14.24, 176.85, 65.21, 9.92, 15.02, 12.9, 21.4, 59.94, 64.62, 37.53, 147.89, 36.52, 97.67, 16.65, 22.1, 23.38, 76.85, 16.58, 7.72, 17.75, 91.25, 9.91, 18.46, 4.45, 3.29, 73.18, 19.5, 5.58, 18.85, 28.64, 7.8, 43.74, 4.43, 7.99, 132.4, 41.48, 14.45, 8.78, 8.14, 9.95, 2.46, 16.61, 32.71, 17.74, 4.46, 68.25, 34.55, 9.92, 181.31, 37.63, 125.22, 25.37, 24.45, 220.92, 11.09, 35.46, 588.56, 58.21, 22.39, 78.55, 135.13, 280.65, 273.41, 381.07, 60.56, 68.63, 40.17, 27.68, 23.68, 23.15, 28.8, 20.94, 21.92, 159.06, 9.94, 127.52, 32.4, 15.93, 99.09, 48.31, 104.66, 257.4, 117.08, 180.32, 66.55, 95.99, 17.74, 30.14, 270.54, 39.8, 54.77, 16.04, 76.99, 5.43, 8.78, 76.96, 10.39, 18.47, 290.11, 48.35, 289.06, 10.44, 57.75, 47.83, 101.62, 96.3, 71.62, 256.97, 149.45, 22.17, 23.15, 89.25, 36.46, 90.03, 69.14, 28.27, 28.72, 17.44, 43.38, 56.72, 84.96, 25.4, 55.06, 47.68, 92.11, 6.65, 30.94, 15.38, 27.44, 516.55, 5.83, 19.45, 41.53, 110.69, 6.82, 54.09, 13.31, 89.8, 25.57, 110.89, 3.32, 93.76, 33.81, 80.87, 30.9, 58.53, 185.22, 4.38, 58.75, 189.53, 7.19, 7.8, 48.97, 28.8, 48.52, 45.96, 309.44, 29.16, 2.22, 255.91, 78.7, 102.67, 33.32, 43.2, 19.5, 91.59, 139.89, 5.51, 213.96, 10.02, 10.03, 39.87, 8.95, 27.74, 7.78, 65.93, 45.41, 263.21, 33.06, 5.54, 59.77, 2.2, 9.95, 14.38, 44.76, 96.45, 15.91, 133.07, 38.03, 36.43, 7.83, 105.41, 20.5, 25.35, 20.55, 119.59, 24.31, 28.81, 101.0, 67.0, 143.85, 20.55, 83.45, 60.62, 25.19, 6.65, 1745.95, 41.62, 44.96, 65.42, 9.92, 24.23, 73.56, 34.35, 75.72, 18.77, 88.59, 312.55, 56.43, 106.61, 11.44, 22.04, 5.73, 197.92, 25.32, 144.83, 145.36, 4.43, 18.33, 48.72, 33.42, 8.83, 18.85, 32.25, 88.56, 14.95, 147.39, 9.25, 35.24, 141.51, 14.41, 5.49, 42.28, 75.69, 16.96, 6.71, 17.33, 710.34, 68.92, 28.39, 24.98, 33.03, 31.06, 46.24, 36.77, 43.74, 11.48, 22.14, 13.21, 15.8, 21.9, 5.51, 20.66, 22.04, 127.0, 21.03, 36.75, 61.45, 42.12, 238.3, 57.43, 28.61, 31.31, 15.43, 8.88, 54.26, 34.01, 5.79, 8.02, 25.68, 19.67, 29.19, 4.38, 15.05, 5.57, 32.31, 81.68, 29.92, 397.98, 119.2, 5.52, 25.54, 12.78, 17.78, 100.97, 253.58, 8.92, 22.04, 22.03, 86.57, 97.27, 106.29, 33.31, 13.34, 35.57, 40.75, 6.57, 23.32, 6.63, 30.09, 62.39, 35.62, 25.23, 5.49, 77.67, 4.41, 8.77, 12.09, 32.0, 7.75, 25.44, 27.57, 25.51, 81.59, 8.83, 64.15, 48.92, 52.25, 2.2, 13.29, 15.52, 320.64, 22.26, 21.03, 79.27, 6.61, 59.38, 40.19, 43.07, 2.26, 20.97, 8.8, 205.43, 51.82, 8.78, 90.72, 6.63, 14.46, 85.62, 72.53, 29.24, 68.81, 67.6, 1.15, 13.15, 17.71, 20.06, 77.42, 167.72, 5.54, 34.45, 5.51, 54.04, 7.8, 79.91, 4.62, 66.39, 164.13, 78.1, 49.72, 19.92, 28.92, 709.25, 18.19, 875.38, 60.92, 5.55, 71.14, 301.2, 27.74, 34.26, 108.78, 88.28, 75.83, 7.82, 8.78, 44.68, 20.98, 41.9, 8.88, 124.18, 198.8, 180.0, 71.61, 119.27, 59.33, 3.28, 43.88, 14.46, 64.34, 158.59, 41.98, 32.28, 14.43, 48.49, 2.36, 14.38, 25.52, 7.83, 2.2, 292.18, 8.97, 36.18, 7.8, 8.89, 43.26, 25.35, 12.29, 6.88, 34.48, 11.09, 16.57, 35.99, 13.45, 6.6, 162.65, 13.23, 26.91, 55.62, 61.4, 48.47, 89.62, 7.77, 6.65, 11.56, 23.28, 6.66, 7.74, 4.62, 5.8, 24.56, 10.16, 8.91, 14.45, 25.37, 6.61, 75.29, 11.03, 36.75, 38.61, 36.52, 17.75, 61.87, 31.92, 120.9, 144.82, 70.98, 19.98, 80.09, 30.17, 35.48, 2.4, 42.15, 24.29, 111.26, 71.9, 158.23, 49.75, 7.75, 13.28, 10.97, 5.51, 34.37, 56.61, 138.83, 231.4, 20.17, 29.89, 20.27, 7.69, 77.35, 12.26, 1144.41, 9.95, 7.72, 196.64, 499.4, 114.38, 24.43, 94.88, 75.15, 4.48, 8.89, 196.05, 95.15, 99.28, 42.36, 234.32, 4.59, 80.97, 237.69, 89.34, 4.51, 6.68, 148.42, 108.58, 5.48, 132.38, 7.94, 204.74, 11.08, 74.24, 146.22, 79.5, 17.68, 10.51, 550.77, 45.35, 23.28, 47.57, 40.56, 114.76, 29.81, 15.51, 11.0, 26.61, 6.74, 142.82, 12.17]
```

Some info about the data:

> Mean: 68.71313036020582, Variance: 19112.931263699986, Standard Deviation: 138.24952536518882, Amount elements in training data: 1166

Histogram of the data:

[image]

**Using the python library for fitting:**

```
x = np.linspace(0,300,1000)
# Gamma
shape, loc, scale = gamma.fit(data, floc=0)
print(shape, loc, scale)
y = gamma.pdf(x, shape, loc, scale)
plt.title('Fitted Gamma')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: fitted gamma]

> Parameters: 0.7369587045435088 0 93.2387797804

**Estimated it myself:**

```
def calculateGammaParams(data):
    mean = np.mean(data)
    std = np.std(data)
    shape = (mean/std)**2
    scale = (std**2)/mean
    return (shape, 0, scale)

eshape, eloc, escale = calculateGammaParams(data)
print(eshape, eloc, escale)
ey = gamma.pdf(x, eshape, eloc, escale)
plt.title('Estimated Gamma')
plt.plot(x, ey)
plt.show()
```

[image: estimated]

> Parameters: 0.247031406055 0 278.155443705

One can clearly see a huge difference.

Comment: Please show what you calculated that was "very far from 1" -- this won't related to whether the moment-based estimates are themselves good or not. If possible give your data  (e.g. if the sample size is small enough to include in your post) and your parameter estimates calculated both ways.

Comment: I have updated my question with data, sample code and plots. I hope this helps clarifying my question.

Comment: You seem not to be sure that you would like to fit a Gamma distribution.  This raises the more fundamental question: why are you going through this exercise in the first place?  What are you hoping to accomplish by fitting *any* distribution to the data?

Comment: @whuber I'm fitting the data in order to be able to make some assumptions about future data - more precisely to identify outlier behaviour. I heard the Gamma/lognorm would be a good fit for this type of data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both the MLEs and moment based estimators are consistent and so you'd expect that in sufficiently large samples from a gamma distribution they'd tend to be quite similar. However, they won't necessarily be alike when the distribution is not close to a gamma.

Looking at the distribution of the log of the data, it is roughly symmetric - or indeed actually somewhat right skew. 
This indicates that the gamma model is inappropriate (for a gamma the log should be left skew).

It may be that an inverse gamma model may perform better for these data. But the same mild right-skew in the logs would be seen with any number of other distributions -- we can't really say much for sure based on the direction of skewness on the log scale.

This may be part of the explanation for why the two sets of estimates are dissimilar -- the method of moments and the MLEs won't tend to be consistent with each other.

You can estimate inverse gamma parameters by inverting the data, fitting a gamma, and then keeping those parameter estimates as is. 
You can also estimate lognormal parameters from mean and standard deviation (several posts on site show how, or see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments)), but the heavier the tail of the distribution, the worse those method of moments estimators will tend to be.

---

It seems (from comments below my answer) that the real issue is that parameter estimates must be updated "on-line" - to take only summary information, not the entire data - and update parameter estimates from the summary information. The reason for using the sample mean and variance in the question is that they can be quickly updated.

However, they're not the only things that can be quickly updated!

Distributions in the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), where $f_{X}(x\mid \theta )=\exp \left(\eta (\theta )\cdot T(x)-A(\theta )+B(x)\right)\,$ have a sufficient statistic, $T(x)$.

(NB here $\theta$ is a vector of parameters, and $T$ is vector of sufficient statistics -- of the same dimension)

For all of the distributions I discuss (gamma, lognormal, inverse gamma) the sufficient statistics are easily updated. For reasons of stability, I suggest updating the following quantities (which between them are sufficient for all three distributions):

- the mean of the data
- the mean of the logs of the data
- the variance of the logs of the data

For actual maximum likelihood, you'd use $s^2_n$ rather than the Bessel-corrected version of the variance, but it doesn't matter all that much (and if you update the Bessel-corrected version you can get the $n$-denominator version easily so it won't matter which you update).

Stable variance-updates should be used. [*Do not* update the mean of the squares and use $\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2-\bar{x}^2$ to compute variance -- that's asking for trouble.]

---

If you want to assess the suitability of the model over time, you will want to store more than sufficient statistics. Binned data might serve for that. A few hundred (say 500 or so) well chosen bins will be barely distinguishable in a plot from raw data (even in a Q-Q plot), but bin counts take little room to store and are rapidly updated. You'll probably need a much wider range of bins than you expect the data to take up, so perhaps 2000 bins total even if only a fraction of them might be used in a plot, and you'll need end-bins that cover values out to the ends of the possible range for the variable ($0$ and $\infty$). I'd suggest binning the logs rather than the original data for model assessment purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what would be a better fitting distribution if I may ask?

Comment: I have made a suggestion in an edit ... an inverse gamma may fit better -- or indeed any number of other possibilities consistent with that observation about the logs.

Comment: I've fitted the inverse gamma using the python library and the results look very promising. However, I can't quite figure out how to find the shape and scale for the invgamma analytically. I thought it would use the same `calculateGammaParams()` function that I wrote and simply inverse the scale and shape, by doing 1/scale and 1/shape. However this seems wrong. The fitted params are `0.918884418421 0 14.8279520471`, while my estimates are `0.247031406055 0 278.155443705`

Comment: A lognormal looks not too bad.

Comment: @NickCox I actually tried a lognormal before giving the Gamma a try. At first glance it seemed that the Gamma fitted better, however I need to be able to estimate the parameters using the sample's mean/variance/std, can this also easily be done for the lognormal?

Comment: I just plotted log of data on a normal quantile plot as a first stab at how well it might work. It's the same issue as with the gamma: many people prefer maximum likelihood (ML) for parameter estimation. I  don't get the self-imposed limitation here to moments methods. Are you saying that ML can't be done in Python? Never used it, but no one here is obliging you to use it!

Comment: Whatever software you use, quantile-quantile plots are immensely preferable to side-by-side comparison of histograms.

Comment: @NickCox The reason for using only the mean and variance is because fetching the actual data is taking too long. Instead we build an algorithm that on a daily basis updates the mean and variance of the data, which resembles all the data seen up till that point - this allows us to do "sequential learning". This however imposes these limitations on the available data. To be honest I never worked with the maximum likelihood before - my knowledge on statistics is rather limited. There is no way to perform ML using only the mean and variance?

Comment: No; you need all the data to do ML. Think about this way: if mean and SD (variance) are enough how could you discriminate between several distributions (normal, gamma, lognormal,  etc.) with the same mean and SD?  Anything else is at best an approximation. As the ML calculation is very fast, I still don't see that even updating imposes a constraint.

Comment: Both answers make very good points.  You said that you wanted to compute the best estimate but restricted it to using only the first two estimated moments.  This will not necessarily lead to a best estimate.  You also need to define what is best.  It is interesting to see how the method of moments estimator differs from maximum likelihood on your data.  Asymptotic properties are interesting but closeness of the estimates depends on the actual sample size.

Comment: @NickCox You don't always need all the data to do ML - if your model is exponential family, just the sufficient statistics will be enough. This is addressed in the answer, where keeping sufficient statistics needed to fit inverse gamma, lognormal and gamma models are suggested as things to collect.

Comment: @Glen_b I take your point, but without the full data you are left with estimates of unknown quality.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly the case; you can't address the suitability of the model beyond the extra statistic. Given the constraint (of having to do it "on-line"), one possibility is to look at histograms on the log scale (since one can have say 1000 bins that cover a considerably wider range than should be needed, make the end bins open-ended, and update that relatively quickly as the data are processed).

Answer (score 10):

The estimates obtained this way are method of moments estimates. In particular, we know that $\mbox{E}(X) = \alpha \theta$ and $\mbox{Var}[X] = \alpha \theta^2$ for a gamma distribution with shape parameter $\alpha$ and scale parameter $\theta$ (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)). Solving these equations for $\alpha$ and $\theta$ yields $\alpha = \mbox{E}[X]^2/\mbox{Var}[X]$ and $\theta = \mbox{Var}[X] / \mbox{E}[X]$. Now substitute the sample estimates to obtain the method of moments estimates $\hat{\alpha} = \bar{x}^2 / s^2$ and $\hat{\theta} = s^2 / \bar{x}$.

Those are not the MLEs (again, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation)). I don't know what library you used for estimating the parameters, but typically such libraries yield MLEs. And those could be rather different than the method of moment estimates.

Also, the "sum under the curve" is not quite the right thing to compute for a continuous random variable -- you really need to integrate. And regardless of what you plug in for $\alpha$ and $\theta$ (of course with the constraint that these parameters must be > 0, this must always integrate to 1.

**Update:**

After posting the data, I used R for obtaining the MLEs and method of moment estimates. This yields:

```
> library(MASS)
> fitdistr(y, dgamma, start=list(shape=1, scale=1))
      shape         scale   
   0.73684030   93.26893829 
 ( 0.02613277) ( 4.59104121)

> mean(y)^2 / var(y)
[1] 0.2468195
> var(y) / mean(y)
[1] 278.3942
```

So, essentially the same as was obtained with Python. So, the estimates simply are just that different using maximum likelihood estimation versus the method of moments.

Comment: I have updated my question with the data, plots and sample code. I believe I used those formula's that you mentioned for calculating the shape and scale. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the information Wolfgang, it is greatly appreciated.